# Is there a power saving way to download torrents?

Tags: software-recommendation, power-management, bittorrent

I usually download my torrents at night, while I'm sleeping. But when doing so, Ubuntu loads the entire desktop interface, while I only need the torrent client. I would like to use an energy saving way of downloading torrents to make my power usage go down.

I know that `transmission-cli` can download torrents in a command line. Such a thing might be the solution, but with `tranmission-cli`, I have to include the torrent's URL to get it running, e.g. `transmission-cli http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent`.

That's not what I want. If a command line interface (CLI) torrent client would be the best way to save power, I want it to import the active torrents from the GUI, including the parts that are already downloaded.

Is there any way to get this done?

I've got Transmission and Deluge already installed, so if it could be done with one of these torrent clients, it would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: Does shutting down the X session actually save any measurable power?

Comment: I don't know, any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Invest in a plug-in power monitor and check :) My point is, it's a fair bit of effort to go to when it might not have any effect. If you're really concerned about power then pick up a less-beefy box like a NAS and run your torrents on that 24/7 might be the way to go, then you can turn off your (possibly much more powerful) desktop at night.

Comment: I have done extensive measurements of power efficiency for PCs from the Pentium IV era to some of the older dual cores, and whether there's a graphical interface running makes virtually no difference. However, there are graphical applications that tend to create a constant load, like open web browsers displaying pages with Flash ads. Flash, especially under Linux, can really keep a CPU busy, thus "costing" 5 to 15 watts more. Other things (basically everything that `powertop` shows) make far more difference in the energy consumption, and by far the most can be saved with an efficient PSU.

Comment: @Caesium: You should, if possible, not use cheap plug-in power meters to measure computers. For one thing, a PC consumes so little energy that systematic errors in how the simple devices do their measurements make up a comparatively large percentage of the displayed value, and more importantly, they generally are not capable of so-called true RMS measurements (which is basically a term for "capable of accurately integrating over the strange power consumption patterns of a computer's PSU"). Borrow a true RMS multimeter with a power measurement adapter instead, perhaps from a hackerspace nearby.

Comment: The best way to use less power it to use a device that uses less power. I have an old eeePC 900 netbook running Lubuntu I keep around for things just like this. Slow as a work station, but it works just fine for downloading torrents and similar unattended tasks. Of course, I happened to have one sitting around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with Deluge:

Firstly  go to `tty1` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>and run `sudo killall Xorg`

Run this:
`sudo apt get install deluge-console deluged`

Use this command to connect with deluge

`deluged&&deluge-console`
use `resume *` to resume all downloads and `halt` to pause them

Use the following commands to control the other parts of Deluge

- `add` Add a torrent
- `config` Show and set configuration values
- `connect` Connect to a new deluge server.
- `debug` Enable and disable debugging
- `del` Remove a torrent
- `exit` Exit from the client.
- `halt` Shutdown the deluge server.
- `help` displays help on other commands
- `info` Show information about the torrents
- `pause` Pause a torrent
- `quit` Exit from the client.
- `resume` Resume a torrent
- `rm` Remove a torrent

---

source: http://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=19115

Answer (score 0):

what about `transmission-daemon`?

```
sudo apt-get install transmission-daemon
man transmission-daemon
```

transmission-daemon and transmission-gtk use the same format for config files, so you can tell transmission-daemon to use gtk's config dir with `--config-dir` flag. the default configuration path for the daemon is `~/.config/transmission-daemon` but the default for gtk-client is `~/.config/transmission`.

config file: `settings.json`

also, the transmission-gtk can also be controlled with the [rpc](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/rpc) clients. Just enable the web ui.

@Exeleration-G
In the gtk-client's settings, select enable web client: Preferences > 'Web' tab, then you can control it with the webui or transmission-remote etc

Note: transmission-cli is deprecated.

Finally: `transmission-daemon -f -g ~/.config/transmission/`

Answer (score 0):

There's this command line bittorrent utility called `ctorrent`. It allows some switches to be used with the command and you can specify the *.torrent* file or trackers URL.

#### Usage:

```
ctorrent [options] *.torrent
```

*(Available at the repository in the Section: `universe/net`)*